# How do I pick up my workbench?

Tags: minicraft

I dropped my bench to make some stuff and have no idea how to pick it up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Equip the Pow Glove, and press Attack near the bench.

Comment: So that's what's it's for!

Comment: Same goes for other crafting stations, too (Furnace, Anvil, …).